# Create a filter with condition in selection with an alert

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a filter containing the Year and the Month like below :

[image]

I want to make a rule to select only one year and two months in that year.
Example : I select 2020 and then April and May.

Can I also add a message alert ? when selecting only one year and one month, a message appears "You should select two months"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a measure to check that the correct month filters have been applied, then display that measure in a card:

```
Check Date Filter = 
    IF ( 
        COUNTROWS ( SUMMARIZE ( 'Calendar', 'Calendar'[Year], 'Calendar'[Month] ) ) <> 2,
        "Please select 2 months",
        ""
    )
```

[image]

[image]